# How to turn off Chrome DevTools console's autocorrect, so it merely suggests alternatives instead of changing what I type?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome devtools has for a while had a handy auto suggest feature. For example, when I type `data`, it suggests other things I might want to choose that start `data`.

[image]

However, with a recent update, it seems to have become more aggressive. If I type `data` and hit return, Chrome decides it knows better than me that I *meant* to type the first item in the suggestions list:

[image]

How can I get the old behaviour back, where it only changes what I typed if I *select* one of the suggestions (e.g. by clicking on it or pressing down)?